# Error finding github action after forking to my organization

Tags: github-actions, github-enterprise, crowdin

There is a github action in the github.com/crowdin organization I would like to use in my github Enterprise org.
As I can't use it directly (or fork it to my org), I have mirror cloned and mirror pushed it into my GHE organization.
When trying to reference it from my actions workflow, I am facing this error:

> Failed to resolve action download info. Error: Unable to resolve action `myorg/github-action@1.2.0`, repository not found on this server. If you want to use this action from GitHub.com, see the following documentation: https://docs.github.com/en/enterprise/admin/github-actions/managing-access-to-actions-from-githubcom

The cloned repository definitely has a 1.2.0 release and according to the github actions readme this is the correct way to reference it.
I am suspecting this might have something to do with the mirror clone and push.
I did get a bunch of errors regarding refs which are pull requests, such as:

> "! [remote rejected] refs/pull/12/head -> refs/pull/12/head (deny updating a hidden ref)"

but from googling this, I got the impression that these are not critical errors for the sake of the mirror clone

Original action repo:
https://github.com/crowdin/github-action

Answer (score 4):

Fixed.
Apparently the github-action repo **has to be public** or the workflow has to include credentials for accessing it (although both are internal to the organization)

Comment: This saved me today!! Thank you @nsteiner